# change of root ownership cause segmentation error

Tags: grub2, root, ownership

I know this could be an smarter question but since I spent a whole day to fix this, then I dare to ask help to save time for redhat exam. I changed the ownership of root to user and then everything started crashing gradually.
I have not been able to login, went through recovery mode and edited the grub file, then grub menu disapeared on following reboot. Installed it again but the system could not be connected to firefox and access to the files and application was denied.

---

I have then tried to "erase disk and install ubuntu20" which comes to grub error after reboot: "fix minimal bash like line editing is supported" after rebooting.

Then tried to fix the error of this new installation with live usb in "try ubuntu mode".
So "fdisk -l", giving back sad1/sda2/sda5. So i mounted root on dev/sda5 (unable to sda2) and was able to mount efi on sda1. then trying to install grub:

sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --bootloader-id=ubuntu  --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi

which throws back "segmentation fault(core dumped)" error, sounds to be a long story by itself.

The reason can be no access to internet connection. Any access to other stuff like, setting of the system, to internet of any kind(wifi/lan) or any application, packge manager is denied. The only thing gets open is terminal.

p.s: editing the post since not being able to add comment on three following comments(posting from an old ifone). Well actually, the errors after *** on the text are coming following the new installation. So i already tried to reinstall. The iso file of ubuntu on my usb was a backup. Could it be also affected by this ownership stuff and cause all this happens after *** in the text?

Comment: You have to have / as owner of system. And about only way to fix is to reinstall & restore from your backups. You may be able to reset to /, but parts of folders & files in / have other system file ownership & permissions. In Ubuntu the `id` command shows all users.

Comment: I agree. This is one of those mistakes that are too messy to try to fix. Your best path is to reinstall the OS and remember not to make this mistake in the future.

Comment: The ownership and permissions of the system's files are set up by the installer at the behest of the developer. Blindly changing them ALL to a single value breaks almost everything. Reinstall.